# Vendor Invoices - Charges Code & Vendor Ledger Dimension

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a charge code called FREIGHT set up with the following configurations. Under Credit, I've specified a ledger account of **4800**.

[image]

I now create a Purchase Order, confirm and go through the whole process, and then try to invoice / post it.

I'm presented the following error:

**"The combination 4800- is not valid for the account structure MYACCOUNTSTRUCTURE"**

So it's been identified that AX is attempting to use 4800 from the aforementioned charges code field **MarkupTable.VendorLedgerDimension**.

In the code, it crashes in the **PurchFormLetter.run()** method, and if I did further it goes into the **SysOperationController\pack** super(); class before it crashes.

Now, if I were to change my account from 4800 to for example 2100, then the invoice goes through fine, which is good.

My question, and what I need is to find out what class / where in the code is this happening during the invoice post process that AX is trying to use this MarkupTable.VendorLedgerDimension field. I need to access that part of the process and modify that value (obviously 4800 is just the display value) to be something else.

If anyone needs more information for background, I need to keep the account for FREIGHT at 4800, while setting the actual financial dimension to the financial dimension on the line item. I've been debugging and looking all over the place for where this process occurs, but have had no luck so far.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check what dimensions are mandatory on this account. Then set financial dimension on invoce lines.

Comment: Where would I go to do that? I do in fact want it to use the invoice line financial dimension instead of the markup code charge ledger account

Comment: On invoice form (vendEditInvoice) on fast tab "Line details" there is a tab "Financial dimensions". You can set your dimensions there. On fast tab "Lines" in action pane there is a button group "Financials" and button "Distribute amounts". In this form you can see tha actual ledger dimension for posting.